# Undeclare a class in PHP

Tags: php

I have a daemon processing quite a bit of MVC logic in the background that includes the classes it needs on demand. Sometimes, however, it comes to a point where it includes two identically named classes from different modules within one cycle. Ideally, I would like to "undeclare" a class before I include it again, I cannot find in the PHP manual however, if this is possible.

Something like this:

```
//first foo 
class foo(){ 

} 

//undeclare foo 
undeclare foo; 

//create new foo 
class foo(){ 

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not possible to "undeclare" a class.

You should probably look into PHP's [namespacing](http://uk.php.net/namespace) or, use a convention for naming your classes similar to

```
Application_Module_Class
```

so you would be calling

```
$x = new Application_Foo_Bar;
```

to include the Bar class from the Foo module

This also lends itself quite well to using [autoload](http://uk.php.net/autoload) functions

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these solutions are currently possible in my situation.

Comment: Do you use PHP 5.3? This would offer a solution.

Comment: The application cannot be porter to PHP 5.3 in its current state. It is more than 250 Mb of code ;)

Comment: @powtac could i know the solution for 5.3 ?

Comment: @beliveyourdream Namespacing, as the Answer suggests.