# How to require a PHP file with classes more than once?

Tags: php, doctrine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undeclare a class in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572159/undeclare-a-class-in-php)

There are class A in `A.php`, and B in `B.php`. I create a new instance of B in one of functions of A. In that function I change the B.php file and it's structure, I want to use the new B.php in continue lines of A.php.

If I call `require 'B.php'` it says `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class B`

Is there any way to remove 'class' B from memory and require it again?

I'm using an ORM named Doctrine I have a form builder that generates Files for Entities so When the form submits I have to change an Entity's file and require it again and also use the new object! This is my actual problem

Or Is there any way to include a file as another name like python? in python we say `import sys as MyName`

Comment: This sounds like a poor design, especially if you're asking about forcing PHP to redeclare a previously defined class. You may want to reconsider your approach.

Comment: changing the code of one php script by another seems very strange to me. do you realy **need** it?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? And how would you like to remove all these instances of `B` and all classes inheriting from `B`, plus all their instances? This is very poorly written piece of software, unless you will explain the reasons for doing this.

Comment: You should explain what you want to do. Maybe there is a more appropriate solution than this one.

Comment: I wouldn't jump on someone and declare their software poorly written until they have explained their reasons. I write "bad code" all the time, just to see if something works, to experiment, and test the limits of the language.

Comment: @Leigh Thank you finally someone that makes sense.

Comment: @Leigh: It is possible, but if this happens in a simple application, it would be hard for me to believe it is well written. Although I would be happy to hear what is the reason for what OP wants to achieve. No disrespect.

Comment: @sinoohe: What is it you actually need to change in the class? Is it really so dynamic it can't be set up during the constructor, or using a factory method?

Comment: @Leigh I have a form builder using Doctrine, I want to generate entity files or change them, Every Entity file referes to a class so If I change a file tha class that that links to will be changed! The problem is in the code generator section that I'm using that class  that I'm changing the file of that!!!

Comment: @sinoohe It sounds to me like you need to implement a factory class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are classes the same on both you a.php and b.php,

Answer (score -5):

You have to use the function `require_once('B.php')` or `include_once('B.php')` this way it wont send warning. There i sno need to remove the class from the memory. WP uses this functions.

https://www.php.net/include_once

https://www.php.net/require_once

Comment: -1 No, read the question. Not only is your answer incorrect, it does not help the OP at all.

Comment: Dude why you do vote -1, the problem is not the design. OK. Its the code

Comment: Because not only is your answer false (both functions will raise the SAME error that the OP posted), it doesn't answer the original question, hence a loving -1 vote.

Comment: And I think it's hilarious that you think I'd care that you viewed my profile and downvoted my top questions and answers on StackOverflow. Oh, the maturity. Bravo.